# How to convert numpy array of image with varying resolution to standard image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a point cloud of an object and I want to generate a basic image of the object.

In my local device I can use
plt.scatter(x,y,0.1,c=z)

Then save the image with no axis.

However, I am limited on my other system in not being able to use matplotlib and only being able to use skimage, numpy or cv2.

if I reshape z to align with x,y the image doesn't look the same because x and y have varying resolutions. That is, x spans from -1 to 1 with 200 points and y from 0 to 1 with 400 points. Thus reshape yields a skewed image of size (400,200). Skewed in the sense that on my local computer a plt.imshow yields a skew image in comparison to the first. How can I transform the image to look like the first?

Comment: can't you do this for `(400, 400)` and use `x*2`

Comment: maybe better show both images - to see difference.

Comment: reshape is the wrong operation. you seem to want `cv.resize` (or the skimage equivalent). or maybe you want to scale your point coordinates appropriately before you draw them.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer at all. You don't say what you can use to generate the image with one of skimage, numpy or cv2, and the sentence "if I reshape z to align with x,y the image doesn't look the same..." sounds pretty mysterious. And what is a *basic* image ?

Comment: It's basically a point cloud. I can't show the image. But the idea is that I have a point cloud and need a png image of it.